# How to restart a Binding of Isaac game without menuing

Tags: nintendo-switch, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

I just bought the Binding of Isaac Afterbirth+ for nintendo Switch and read the manual. The `+` button is said to be menu/restart but I can't figure out how to restart without menuing (quit game -> new game).

I’ve seen Youtube videos where the player keep restarting using a single key press until a good starter item is available, so I know it's at leat possible on PC.

How do I achieve the same on Switch?

Comment: On PC, you need to hold down R for a few seconds. Try holding the + button.

Comment: @Studoku I tried, the menu poped up immediately, I continued to hold it for like 10 seconds, nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of January 9th 2019, the Forgotten update is released, and with it comes the ability to do a quick reset on the Switch. You can do this by pressing and holding both joysticks at the same time.

Comment: Ernest answer is right.I guess they added it on a later update, so this is outdated.

Comment: @WestsideTony Unless Ernest answers my comment to detail the steps involved, I’m not accepting their answer as I can't make it work.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger on the lates version of The Binding of Isaac for Nintendo Switch, as of today, if you press the 2 stick for 1 second the run restarts.On handheld mode.

Comment: @WestsideTony Guess I'll be able to confirm [around next week](https://twitter.com/HeadupGames/status/1104075611721662464?s=20) and change the checkmark accordingly, if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can restart it by pressing the left and right stick for a few seconds. Or if you're playing with one controller of them I think it just hold left/right stick and A/B/X/Y I think.

Unfortunately I restarted some good runs by accident and would like to know how to disable this combination :( especially if you are playing with one controller...

Comment: How do you hold them? I'm pressing (without moving) both of them for several second and nothing happens.